# Looking for an on/off digital toggle signal chip

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit

I am looking for a chip that will enable me to input 3-12 V DC on 2 pins (+ and ground input), to get as output on 2 other pins, the exact voltage i put in those previous 2 input pins (+ and ground output) and to have a 5th pin, that if i put in a 3-12 V DC signal - Will turn on and off the electricity that goes between the previous 4 pins (+ and ground input and output).

I understand that maybe such a chip can be found on Motorola chip series MC140xx or 74HCxx or on the LMxxx (which is not Motorola, but another manufacturer, that starts with the letter N - i forgot its name).

Anyway - i need the chip to be as less expensive as possible.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Roi.

Comment: How much current will be drawn by the load (what ever is connected to the "2 other pins")?

Comment: Does it have to be a chip? How quick does it need to be able to switch the circuits open and closed?

Comment: How about an analog switch (CD4066, etc)? As others are asking, figuring out the precise part requires knowing more about your requirement.  Andy seems to perhaps be hinting towards a mechanical or solid-state relay, which gives you some immunity from the details of the switched circuit, at some cost and slowness.

Comment: Do you really need to switch the ground?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest soution which will have no voltage drop is a relay.

Comment: The current drawn will not be more than 3-4 amps. It is for a 2-3S LiPo with a few servos. It does not have to be a chip. It has to be not big and inexpensive. It has to switch between open and close only several times a minutes - no speed issue regarding the on/off function.

Comment: I am trying to build a circuit to protect my 1000 mAh 3S LiPos, from over discharging. I am using also an Arduino and Low voltage LiPo alarm buzzers - and at the end point i have several small servos. I think that the problems with all these chips, is that although on the logic and analog side, they do exactly what i need, but they will not can't stand such a current as the LiPos let out. So i started searching for relays - but ones that have DC voltage of around 3-20V, not only for logic, but also 3-20 V DC for load - are rare and expensive. 
Do you have any idea for a solution?